# How can I eliminate a quote from the start of my string using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings that sometimes start like this:

```
"[1][v5r,vi][uk]
```

Other times like this:

```
[1][v5r,vi][uk]
```

How can I remove the `"` when it appears at the start of a string using Regex? I know I need to do something like this, but not sure how to set it up:

```
regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[ant=[^\]]*\]");
regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));
```

Comment: Your first two strings are identical

Comment: If you just want to remove a leading `"` from the start of a string, it'd be easier to use Substring. Your regex is significantly more complex than this, which implies there are extra requirements that you're not telling us. What are they?

Comment: See if [String.TrimStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=netframework-4.8) does what you need. It would be far simpler.

Comment: I want to remove everything that comes before the [1]

Comment: @canton7 - thanks, I fixed this. My bad copy / paste

Comment: @Alan2 So remove everything -- not just quotes? Does the string always start with `[1]`?

Comment: regex seems a big hammer to crack a nut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string always starts with `[1]`:

```
int indexOfFirstElement = item.IndexOf("[1]");

if (indexOfFirstElement > 0)
    item = item.Substring(indexOfFirstElement);
```

If you just want to start at the first `[`:

```
int indexOfFirstElement = item.IndexOf('[');

if (indexOfFirstElement > 0)
    item = item.Substring(indexOfFirstElement);
```

Simpler than Regex, which is probably overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
string input =@" ""[1][v5r,vi][uk]";
string pattern = @"^\s*""?|""?\s*$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You can find my Example here in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WM0boD)

Comment: Hello, can you include the [1] into your pattern as the part of every string that I need starts with that.

Comment: @Alan2 pattern is different from the input, [1] is included in the input

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the code works good but I was just trying to understand the pattern you use and noticed it does not include a "[" so  it's confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

string.StartsWith will do the trick

```
string str = "\"[1][v5r,vi][uk]";
if(str.StartsWith('"'))
    str = str.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `indexOf` and `Substring`

```
string str = "\"a[1][v5r,vi][uk]";
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('[')));
```

Answer (score 0):

use `TrimStart()` to remove this character if exists

```
string str = "\"a[1][v5r,vi][uk]";
str= str.TrimStart('\"');
```